# Updating an object inside a an array field in firestore

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update an object inside an array which is a field in a firestore document. And so I filter through the objects in that array to get the object I am looking for. But the question is how can I update it? I have tried doing this but I get an error saying ...update is not a function.

```
 db.collection('conversations').doc(convoid).onSnapshot(snap=>{
    snap.data().messages.filter(msg=>msg.msgid==msgid).update({
      messages: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(messages)
    })
  })
```

Any suggestions?
UPDATE: Just to elaborate, there is a firestore document that contains a messages  array, and each message has its own msgid. Therefore when I click on a message in my app, i have access to the msgid, and now i want to use this msgid to filter the msgs in the messages array and update that specific message

Answer (score 1):

`snap.data()` is not the "document" as such; it's an object with the *fields* of a document.  It does not contain a DocumentReference, and does not have an `.update()` method.

the value `snap` also does not have an `.update()` method, BUT it *does* have a `ref` property, which you can use as `db.doc(snap.ref).update(...`.

Also, `.filter()` returns/creates an array, which does not have any form of `.update()`

it strikes me you are *trying* to do:

```
db.collection('conversations').doc(convoid).onSnapshot(snap=>{
    db.doc(snap.ref).update({
      messages: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
          snap.data().messages.filter(msg=>msg.msgid==msgid))
    })
  })
```

Obviously, you are doing more than this - but note that `.arrayUnion()` will *add* the value(s) to the array, and may not *replace* the value(s).

Comment: when doing this i recieve an error 'u.indexOf' is not a function

Comment: Just to elaborate, there is a firestore document that contains a messages  array, and each message has its own msgid. Therefore when I click on a message in my app, i have access to the msgid, and now i want to use this msgid to filter the msgs in the messages array and update that specific message